# Speeding up Screen Captures in While Loops

Tags: python, pynput

I'm new to python and I'm trying to make a bot to play FNF. Obviously this means I need a bot that's fast, but my code runs really slow. I know this is because the processes I'm doing are quite heavy, but I don't know how to speed it up.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import PIL.ImageGrab
import time

keyPresser = Controller()

while True:

    pic = PIL.ImageGrab.grab((2000, 400, 2001, 401))
    pic2 = pic.convert("RGB") 
    rgbPixelValue = pic2.getpixel((0, 0))
    if rgbPixelValue != (134, 163, 173):
        keyPresser.press(Key.left)
    
    print(rgbPixelValue)
```

Comment: What makes you think your process is "quite heavy"? It doesn't appear to be. How quickly is it iterating? How quickly do you want it to run?

Comment: @David it iterates around 2 times a second, but for the purpose I'm looking for it needs to be far faster, around 10-20 times a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you are calling `.press()`. However, I think you actually want to press and release the key. This can be done by calling `keyPresser.release(Key.left)` directly after calling `.press()` or by just calling `keyPresser.tap(Key.left)`. The current speed at which it is repeating is probably just the repeat limit define by your OS.

Edit: Turns out `ImageGrab` is just too slow (it uses a system command and the filesystem). You could use it with some form of multithreading (like `concurrent.futures`), but you should probably use something designed for fast capture. A quick google search turns up [mss](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/index.html) which is much faster:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image

keyPresser = Controller()

with mss() as sct:
    for i in range(100):
        pic = sct.grab((200, 400, 201, 401))
        pic2 = Image.frombytes("RGB", pic.size, pic.bgra, "raw", "BGRX")
        rgbPixelValue = pic2.getpixel((0, 0))
        if rgbPixelValue != (134, 163, 173):
            keyPresser.tap(Key.left)
        
        print(rgbPixelValue)
```

This (appears to) achieves about 100 iterations per second on my computer.

Comment: I tried that and it did solve another problem I was having, however as you can see from the code, the script also prints the RGB value of the pixel in the chat. The speed of this didn't change when implementing your suggestion

Comment: Interesting! Just tested here and I get about 15 iterations per second. Most of the time is spent capturing the image. Turns out `ImageGrab` just isn't good for this (looking at the source code it uses a system command, saves to a file, reads the fiel... It's never going to be fast).

Comment: Alright, I'll look into some alternate method. One of the problems might be that I have a mac, which are kinda notorious for being slow. Thanks though!

Comment: @pheonix0455 I've updated my answer with an alternative (way faster). Regarding Mac, I'm also using one.

Comment: @ David thanks for that. I'm at school right now and the school wifi doesn't let me download libraries but once I get home I'll try it.

Comment: No, just Python directly. What is odd?

Comment: I just find it strange you get so many more iterations than me on the same hardware. Maybe I'm missing something though

Comment: We may not actually be on exactly the same hardware, though the difference does seem significant. Without downloading a library, your only other option would be multithreading. Or wait til you get home ;-)

Comment: I'll update you in a few hours :)